# error al ejecutar una aplicación de nest básica con typeORM y postgresl

Tags: nodejs, postgresql, docker, nestjs

Estoy creando mi primera aplicación con nestjs y typeorm (postgresql), por ahora empece a ejecutar mi código y tengo el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi código es muy básico, voy a compartir:

**app.module.ts**
Estoy seguro que está fallando la parte de la base de datos, cuando quito la configuración de la base de datos el código funciona.

```
 import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
    import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
    import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
    
    @Module({
      imports: [
        ConfigModule.forRoot(),
        TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
          type: 'postgres',
          host: process.env.DB_HOST,
          port: +process.env.DB_PORT,
          database: process.env.DB_NAME,
          username: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
          password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,      
          autoLoadEntities: true,
          synchronize: true,
        }),
      ],
    })
    export class AppModule {}
```

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:14.3
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DB_NAME}
    container_name: teslodb
    volumes:
      - ./postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

**.env**

```
DB_PASSWORD=admin
DB_NAME=teslodb
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=5432
DB_USERNAME=postgres
```

Comment: Has probado poner el puerto con `parseInt(process.env.POSTGRES_PORT, 10)`?

Answer (score 0):

Yo veo un error de tipado en:

```
port: +process.env.DB_PORT,
```

Veo un **+** extra